# Does Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality in unbounded domain still hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Often we have the following Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality: Let $1\leq p_1, p_2\leq \infty$, $0\leq r<l (r, l\in Z_+)$. Suppose that the number 
$$
\theta=\frac{n/p-n/p_1-r}{n/p_2-n/p_1-l}
$$
satisfies the inequality $r/l\leq \theta<1$. Then
$$\|u\|_{r, p}\leq C\|u\|_{0, p_1}^{1-\theta}\|u\|_{l, p_2}^\theta.$$

We have known that the inequality holds if the domain is bounded with regular boundary.
I wonder if it still holds when the domain is unbounded in $R^n$ with $n\leq 3$?
It seems true because some people usually use the fact in proving some theorems.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If I recall correctly from my analysis class, it is indeed true. You can approximate with compactly supported functions to extend to all of $R^n$

Comment: Thank you very much! What about $n>3$? Is still true?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a difference between $n\leq 3$ and $n>3$?